# appletviewr - getParameter returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I compile this code and use applet viewer for testing. But I see string "value: null" instead of "value: VALUE".

**1)** What did I do wrong?

```
/*  <applet code="Demo" width="100" height="100">
    <param name="name1" value="VALUE">
    </applet>
*/
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Demo extends Applet
{
    String str=null;
    public void init()
    {
        str=getParameter("name1");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("value: "+str,100,50);
    }
}
```

But if I open HTML file which is located in same folder with `Demo.class`

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code=Demo.class width="200" height="200" >
<param name="name1" value="VALUE">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I get desired output "value: VALUE". (However for this result I should kill process `java.exe`, otherwise I get non-updated applet although Demo.class was updated).

**2)** Why won't the applet update until I will the `java.exe`?

Comment: I made some edits to make the question(s) more clear.  Please review them carefully, and change anything I got wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting `value: VALUE` in the applet viewer here.  But then that is after increasing the width of the applet element from 100 to 200 in the comment at the top of the source.  Thinner than that, and the text becomes ***truncated.***